# RestAssured returns array instead of String

Tags: arrays, string, rest-assured

I have this test I'm writing in RestAssured. I want to extract the id in String but always returning it as array. This is the test I have written so far.

```
@Test(priority = 1)
    public static void searchForUsername( ) throws Throwable {
        ValidatableResponse response= given().contentType(ContentType.JSON).queryParam("username",
                "Delphine").log().parameters().get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users").then().log().all();

        JsonPath extractor = response.extract().jsonPath();
        userId = extractor.getString("id");
        System.out.println(userId);
    }
```

It prints it as [9] instead of 9

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reason**: the object that you extract is in an array. So when you extract, the `id` will be in an array.

**Solution**: From list of `id`, you can get by index.

```
@Test
void name2() {
    Response res = RestAssured.given()
            .queryParam("username", "Delphine")
            .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
    int id = (Integer) res.jsonPath().getList("id").get(0);
    System.out.println(id);
}
```